# Custom preprocessing in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I use caret for my Machine Learning pipelines. When I have to perform some preprocessing that is not avaliable in the `preProcess` function, is it possible to create a custom function that can be used instead of the default methods?

Answer (score 6):

Not yet, but I'm 80% done with an interface to `caret` that uses [`recipes`](https://topepo.github.io/recipes/) as the model specification tool. That would allow you to create [custom](https://topepo.github.io/recipes/articles/Custom_Steps.html) preprocessing methods.

If you want to try it, use the `recipe_integration` branch of `caret` on github.